# Ambiguous tag: [build]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

The [build](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/build) (x31) tag seems ambiguous. It either relates to:

- building a computer or accessories
- building software (e.g. with `make`, etc.)

What should we do with these?

> <sub>**Note:** I stick to answering my own question since, this way, it's easier to reach consensus on a possible solution.</sub>

Answer (score 7):

We should disambiguate it and use the following tags:

- Use [computer-building](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/computer-building) (x231) for everything related to building PCs on your own. In our case, these are only 9 questions (of which 2 are closed and probably to be deleted). – **done**.
- Doing so, also make a synonym [system-building](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/system-building) → [computer-building](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/computer-building). - **done**
- Keep [build](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/build) for everything related to software building and create the appropriate tag wiki (mention the "computer building" alternative there) – **done**.